# jquery slideToggle not working when working with bootstrap v4

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble with jquery slideToogle.
it works when I use the regular toggle (hide/show). Also there no problem when I use bootstrap's v4 'collapes'. But i wanted to have custom jquery instead to have more control like the speed of the slide.

Here is my codes below :
Jquery:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reservas").click(function(){
        $("#reservas_form").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: here is the error message I am getting in the console log :
Index.html:18 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slideToggle is not a function
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (Index.html:18)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the slim version of jQuery and it doesn't include .slideToggle(). Try including the regular version of jQuery to resolve your issue. I believe bootstrap uses the slim version by default.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a newbie. Glad to know that there is a slim version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

the slim version excludes the effects like the animation expected from slideToggle; so the function isn't defined.

> Slim build
>
> Sometimes you don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many
>   standalone libraries that focus on ajax requests. And often it is
>   simpler to use a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all
>   your web animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that
>   includes the ajax and effects modules, we’ve released a “slim” version
>   that excludes these modules.

A working example with jquery

```js
$("#menu").click(function(){
        $("#content").slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

```css
#content{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">Show Menu</div>
<div id="content">Menu Contnet</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a newbie. Glad to know that there is a slim version of jquery.